# Get TYPO3 trunk from github by git

Tags: git, github, typo3

I would like to get latest tags from main TYPO3 repository.

TYPO3 proposes [short manual](http://wiki.typo3.org/Git_Clone) how to use it's github repository, but it doesn't help. In my case, after `git pull`, there are no latest tags when I'm doing `git tag`.

If I will remake `git clone` of the same URL, I could see latest tags.

Probably, this question is common for all github repositories.

git version 1.7.1, if it could help.

Comment: What do you mean by "latest tags"?  Can you give an example of a tag which you think should be being fetched, but aren't, when you do `git pull`?  Also, which branch are you on when running `git pull`?

Comment: I would like to get TYPO3_4-6-3 tag. Currently, I have the latest TYPO3_4-6-2 tag from stable TYPO3 4.6.x release. git status shows, what i'm on branch master.

Comment: you know what github is? This has nothing to do with github, it's just plain git. I just editied the wiki and remove that hint. But thanks for the docs!

Comment: @StephenKing Probably it's plain git, but this information could help to community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `TYPO3_4-6-3` tag points to a commit that is not contained in any branch.  You can see this in a freshly cloned repository because there's no output from:

```
git branch -a --contains TYPO3_4-6-3
```

By default, `git fetch` (which is called by `git pull`) only fetch tags that point to commits which are on one of the fetched branches.  To force the fetching of all tags, regardless of whether they're on a branch or not, you can run:

```
git fetch --tags
```

And then you should be able to do:

```
git checkout -b my-new-work TYPO3_4-6-3
```

... or whatever.

The relevant bit of the documentation to back up what I'm saying about the behaviour of `git fetch` is [here](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-fetch.html#_description):

> When <refspec> stores the fetched result in remote-tracking branches, the tags that point at these branches are automatically followed. This is done by first fetching from the remote using the given <refspec>s, and if the repository has objects that are pointed by remote tags that it does not yet have, then fetch those missing tags. **If the other end has tags that point at branches you are not interested in, you will not get them.**

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Thank You very much Mark ! git fetch --tags did the job ! Will add this to TYPO3 community wiki.